# How to pass List <AudioTrack> from class to class AudioPlayer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, background, audio-player

The site is an example of microsoft for Windows Phone 7, namely: [Background Audio Player Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) or [Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219073)
In this example, the playlist is formed in the class AudioPlayer as a list of

```
    private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
    new AudioTrack(new Uri("Kalimba.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                    "Kalimba", 
                    "Mr. Scruff", 
                    "Ninja Tuna", 
                    null),

    new AudioTrack(new Uri("Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                    "Maid with the Flaxen Hair", 
                    "Richard Stoltzman", 
                    "Fine Music, Vol. 1", 
                    null),

    new AudioTrack(new Uri("Sleep Away.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                    "Sleep Away", 
                    "Bob Acri", 
                    "Bob Acri", 
                    null),

    // A remote URI
    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                    "Episode 29", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                    null)
};
```

And I have a question, for example if I make it in MainPage.cs:

```
 private static List<AudioTrack> playList2 = new List<AudioTrack>
{
    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://myserver.com/tracks/track1.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                    "MyTrack1", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                    null),

    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://myserver.com/tracks/track2.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                    "MyTrack2", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                    null),

    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://myserver.com/tracks/track3.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                    "MyTrack3", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio", 
                    "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                    null)
};
```

which will be links to several Internet radio in the class MainPage, is it possible to transmit in AudioPlayer. Advise what to do, where to dig. Help me

Comment: Does your app only ever build the playlist in the UI? If not move the code for this into the agent (or a library shared by both) This way the agent can get more tracks to extend the playlist even if the UI isn't running. You can also reduce the amount to communication between app and agent which helps avoid further problems.

Comment: >Does your app only ever build the playlist in the UI? Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write the information to IsolatedStorage or a database from the client application, then read it from the AudioPlayer agent.

To clarify:
Whether you're playing local files or stream files you will communicate with the Agent by writing that info to a DB table or a file in IsolatedStorage.  Say you have a database with a table named Playlist.

From your app or `MainPage.xaml.cs` (or viewmodel) write the data to the playlist table.  Then issue `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();`

Then, in the `AudioPlayerAgent` read from the Playlist table to get the data to create an `AudioTrack`.

update:
Originally I was using IsolatedStorage for this and it worked, now I'm using SterlingDB.  This works pretty well as I can write play list records out to SterlingDB in my client app and read them one at a time in the Agent as the currentTrackIndex is manipulated, all without having to create an SterlingDB index.

Comment: This is probably for local files?
And if my playlist consists of links to the tracks? be like? I added some text above ...

Comment: It's for both.  If your streaming or playing local.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense, I'll add more info.

Comment: Curious as to the reason for the down vote, I'd like to hear the alternatives.  I got this tip from Matt Lacey, it seems to work well.

Comment: Dumb question -- how is the AudioPlayer "registered"?  I can't see in that sample code where anything passes along a handle to AudioPlayer.cs.

Comment: `AudioPlayer` is registered int he `WMAppManifest.xml`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I do exactly the same as you mentioned. The UI app saves the list to IsolatedStorageSettings and the AudioPlayer loads it. But it always loads the same list, even if it's modified. I can see that in the UI app that it's modified, not the same list, but the AudioPlayer always loads the same. I also tried to make a class library with a class that saves/loads this data using mutex and it's no better. Could someone help me?

Comment: That's strange, have you use the `ISETool.exe` to see what's actually being written?

Answer (score 0):

It works for windows phone 8

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new 
         Uri("http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
        "title", "artist", "album", new Uri("albumArtUrl", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```